# Submodule commit object 'Not a valid object name' when using 'git cat-file -p'

Tags: git

I've been familiarizing myself a bit more with git internals and the different git objects. I have a simple repository with one .txt file in the top directory, two .txt files (file1.txt and file2.txt) in a directory called 'my-directory' and a submodule called 'my-submodule'. I get an error when I try to run `$ git cat-file -p {submodule git commit object SHA-1}` and I'm unable to figure out why. I'm showing all the commands I'm running, below and hope someone can help me out.

```
$ git cat-file -p master
tree fcc88590212b42b31803217036a93a9edfe4af1c
parent ae767cc2edd396e63f127d4f3354f769645a3dc4
author Martin
committer Martin

Awesome commit


$ git cat-file -p fcc88590212b42b31803217036a93a9edfe4af1c
100644 blob 21735012b86a0c6c266eb7fb629a777ca70848c1  my-file.txt
040000 tree 4df930165b3c59c0f5dc134ed76d889e4d177d2f my-directory
160000 commit 93a431b481f9ca2b498c94b0c0641e54f00322e0 my-submodule

$ git cat-file -p 21735012b86a0c6c266eb7fb629a777ca70848c1
This is the content of 'my-file.txt'

$ git cat-file -p 4df930165b3c59c0f5dc134ed76d889e4d177d2f 
100644 file1.txt
100644 file2.txt

$ git cat-file -p 93a431b481f9ca2b498c94b0c0641e54f00322e0
fatal: Not a valid object name 93a431b481f9ca2b498c94b0c0641e54f00322e0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cat-file` shows you objects from current repository, but a submodule it is a separate repository. So, the commit-id `93a43…` is a commit from a different object storage. You should navigate to submodule's directory and try from there:

```
$ cd my-submodule
$ git cat-file -p 93a431b481f9ca2b498c94b0c0641e54f00322e0
```

I imagine git figures out that a particular tree entry is a submodule by type of object. I.e. if an entry type is a:

- "blob" - it is just a file,
- "tree" - it is a sub-directory,
- "commit" it is a sub-module.

Comment: Each `tree` entry has those mode strings in it (literally, as ASCII text); they tell Git what to *assume* about the target object. However, you're correct that each object also has its own type embedded within it, so there can be compatibility issues. A blob object is a valid lookup result for modes `100644` and `100755` (file) but also for `120000` (symlink), for instance; but no other object type would be valid for those three modes. Anyway this is all just side notes: as you say, the commit hash in the gitlink is the hash ID in the *other repository*.

Comment: @torek  Seems you are right, it checks `mode==160000` to recognise submodules: https://github.com/git/git/blob/b14f27f91770e0f99f64135348977a0ce1c7993a/git-submodule.sh#L882